# "let: Symbol's value as variable is void" when loading .dir-locals

Tags: debugging, directory-local-variables, let-binding

I have the following `.dir-locals`:

```
((nil . ((eval . (let ((project-root-dir (expand-file-name (locate-dominating-file default-directory ".dir-locals.el"))))
                   (defun tokenize-set-strings ()
                     "Parse the contents of res/set/string.set and process them into src/core/string.hpp tokens."
                     (let ((string-set-file (format "%s/res/set/string.set" project-root-dir))
                           (current-file (buffer-file-name (current-buffer)))
                           (target-file (format "%s/src/core/sstring.hpp" project-root-dir))
                           (tokenizer-prog (format "%s/bin/util/stokenizer" project-root-dir)))
                       (if (string= string-set-file current-file)
                           (if (not (file-exists-p target-file))
                               (error (format "%s does not exist." target-file))
                             (if (not (file-exists-p tokenizer-prog))
                                 (error (format "Could not find tokenizer at %s." tokenizer-prog))
                               (shell-command (format "%s %s %s" tokenizer-prog target-file string-set-file)))))))
                   (add-hook 'after-save-hook 'tokenize-set-strings))))))
```

The idea here is that whenever I edit a project-specific `string.set` file, it will then run an external program called `stokenizer` once the file is saved. I don't want this functionality anywhere else.

The function on its own works fine, but when it's called via the hook, Emacs complains:

`let: Symbol’s value as variable is void: project-root-dir`

I'm not sure why it's not working, and would appreciate any tips. In the mean time, I get around this issue by calling binding `project-root-dir` an additional time, this time with `let*`, inside the function.

Comment: Try adding `;;; -*- lexical-binding: t -*-` at the top of your `.dir-locals.el` file.

Comment: @NickD Tried it, didn't work -- same issue.

Comment: `M-x toggle-debug-on-error`, open a file that will trigger the function and see if there is a backtrace produced. If yes, add it to your question.

Comment: @NickD Dir-local settings are not loaded, so `hack-local-variables` is not applied and your suggestion does not work. Dir-local settings are read and `eval`-ed. The `eval` is executed in `hack-one-local-variable` without the `lexical` argument. So, it creates `lambda`s and not `closure`s. Maybe, backquoting would be a solution. Another strategy would be to use `(eval '(let (...) ...) t)` , i.e., `eval` with non-nil `lexical`-argument.